# Prove: If in all subgraphs of $G$ there is a vertex of degree $<2$ then $G$ is a forest

Tags: graph-theory

I need help proving this:

> Given a graph $G$, prove that if in all subgraphs of $G$ there is a vertex of degree less than $2$ ($1$ or $0$) then $G$ is a forest.

Comment: Where do you get stuck? Plug in the definition of forest, tree, subgraph.

Comment: Assume there is a cycle in $G$...

Comment: Is it sufficient to prove that in all connected components of $G$ there is no cycle and that means it is a forest?

Comment: What can those connected components look like? Consider subgraphs with three vertices.

Comment: yep, a forest is a bunch of trees. each connected component is a tree, and a tree is a connected graph with no cycles

Comment: Thank you so much for the hint, Damian Sobota.
I proved it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to prove the contrapositive? Like Damian said, assume that G is not a forest. Then it has a cycle. This cycle is a subgraph. What is the minimum degree of any vertex in a cycle?

To do this proof you just need to make sure you know the definitions of forest, cycle, and vertex, and that you know how to use contraposition. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition/) has a definition and some examples if you need help with how to use this.